# Getting hyperref to work with \citeyear and \citeyearpar in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

When used in concert with the `hyperref` package, `biblatex` automatically creates hyperrefs for citations but not if they are inserted using `\citeyear` or `\citeyearpar`.
Is it possible to add a hyperref to year only citations?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = {Doe, John D.},
  title = {Hyperrefs to citations},
  journaltitle = {Links Everywhere},
  volume = {1},
  date = {2000},
  pages = {1--2},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

citet -- \citet{ref1}

citeyear -- \citeyear{ref1}

citeyearpar -- \citeyearpar{ref1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One has to redefine the citation commands instructing to use hyperlink, namely:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {}
    {\bibhyperref{\printdate}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
```

Comment: I think `\printfield{year}` should be preferred over `\printdate` in some cases: If there is a month given, the standard `\citeyear` command would only print the year, whereas `\printdate` outputs the month as well. `\printfield{year}` avoids this.

Comment: Actually, the ideal solution should also include the extrayear field, so that multiple publications on a same year get the correct letter after the year, e.g. 1997a, 1997b, 1997c. This can be done by replaceing `\bibhyperref{\printdate}` with `\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}\bibhyperref{\printfield{extrayear}}`

Comment: I suggested an edit to the answer above as these functions should also handle prenote and postnote fields, so that one can add page numbers to them, for instance.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to use the `\cite*` command which is provided by all by all author-year and author-title styles. See the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), section 3.7.2 "Style-specific Commands".

Comment: Be aware though that `\cite*` is a "style-specific" command and as such only available in `authoryear` and `authortitle`; it also changes its behaviour depending on the style used. That is with `authoryear` it prints the year while with `authortitle` it prints the title.

Comment: Yes. My feeling is that the \citeyear behaviour is intentional in biblatex, thus my hint about \cite*. In a numeric citation style you want the [1]; in authortitle you want the title, along with the year. Only in authoryear does the link actually belong with the year, hence the \cite* command.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on Guido's answer, these are similar functions to his but with the following modifications: 1)  use `\printfield{year}` instead of `\printdate` so only the year is printed, 2) use the `extrayear` field so that they handle multiple publications by a same author in a same year (such as 1997a, 1997b, 1997c), and 3) they can use prenote and postnote, so that one can continue to use page numbering such as in `\citeyearpar[3--4]{bib_reference_id}`. The functions are:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}\bibhyperref{\printfield{extrayear}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}[\mkbibparens]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}\bibhyperref{\printfield{extrayear}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Edit: this code above works with `style=authoryear-ibid`. If using `style=authoryear`, substitute both instances of `cite:postnote` for `postnote`.

Comment: I get this error `Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite:postnote' undefined.`  I'm using the `style=authoryear` and `natbib` options to `biblatex` on texlive 2018.

Comment: This are the options I am using with biblates: `bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, ibidtracker=false, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, maxbibnames=9, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, doi=false, isbn=false, urldate=long, dateabbrev=false, eprint=false`. Could you try using these options and see if your problem goes away? If so, it will help you figure out what option is causing the issue.

Comment: From [the accepted answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229868/how-do-i-occasionally-use-standard-style-citation-instead-of-shorthand?rq=1): 'Sometimes the definition of the \cite commands vary across different styles in very minute ways, this is what happens here: postnote vs cite:postnote.' So try using `bibstyle=authoryear-ibid` and `citestyle=authoryear-ibid` and see if the problem goes away. If it does, do report back so I can update my answer.

Comment: My options to `biblatex` are `natbib,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=6,giveninits=true,useprefix=true` .  I'll try the `. . . -ibid` now.

Comment: When I changed `style=authoryear` to `style=authoryear-ibid`, the problem went away.  But, I can't use the latter style.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use the latter style? Regardless, it seems that changing both `cite:postnote` to `postnote` seems to make the problem go away with `authoryear`, could you check that?

Comment: Thanks! I confirm that `postnote` works with `style=authoryear` and `cite:postnote` with `style=authoryear-ibid`.  I said that I can't use the latter style only because that doesn't fit to the standard publication style in our field of science---Sorry for my confusing comment.

Comment: By the way, may I ask why this modification is not done in the biblatex package?

Comment: When I get a chance, I will take a look at their source code and perhaps submit a pull request to their repository. Thanks again for confirming the fix.