# How do I occasionally use standard style citation instead of shorthand

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using biblatex 1.9 with biber 2.9. I use the author-year citation style. Some of my entries have shorthands. On certain occasions, I would like to use the standard citation style for these entries, instead of printing the shorthand. I did not find a citation command for doing this. I now use the workaround

```
\parentext{\citeauthor{entryname}, \citeyear{entryname}}
```

Is there a better approach?

An MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@MISC{ABC,
  AUTHOR     = {Alain B. Cedaire},
  SHORTHAND  = {ABC},
  TITLE      = {Alfabet},
  YEAR       = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,hyperref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}
  Wanted formats, ideally hyperlinked:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \parentext{\citeauthor{ABC}, \citeyear{ABC}}
    \item \citeauthor{ABC} \parentext{\citeyear{ABC}}
  \end{itemize}

  Available formats:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[cite:] \cite{ABC}
    \item[textcite:] \textcite{ABC}
    \item[parencite:] \parencite{ABC}
  \end{itemize}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{biblatex} \addbibresource{marc.bib} \newcommand*\mycite[2][]{\parentext{\citeauthor[#1]{#2}, \citeyear{#2}}} \begin{document} \mycite{Knuth:taocp:1} \end{document}`

Comment: Can you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you use currently use the shorthands.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I was hoping for something within biblatex, which would hopefully preserve hyperlinks. (I am aware of macros.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create  a new command that "forgets" the `shorthand` field for the time being, resulting in a "normal" citation

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenoso}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearfield{shorthand}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitenoso}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearfield{shorthand}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

`\citenoso` is an exact copy of `authoryear-icomp`'s `\cite` macro with the line `\clearfield{shorthand}%` added to the citation hook.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenoso}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearfield{shorthand}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitenoso}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearfield{shorthand}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
\cite{kant:kpv,kant:ku,baez/article} vs \citenoso{kant:kpv,kant:ku,baez/article} and 
\cite{kant:kpv,kant:ku,baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For the occasional use, you could also go with `\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}` and then cite the entry.
Like

```
\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}\cite{kant:kpv}
```

---

With `authoryear-comp` the redefinition is

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenoso}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearfield{shorthand}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitenoso}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearfield{shorthand}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

(Sometimes the definition of the `\cite` commands vary across different styles in very minute ways, this is what happens here: `postnote` vs `cite:postnote`.)

Comment: Nice, so an intermediate solution `\newcommand*{\citenosh}[2][]{\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}\cite[#1]{#2}}` is also possible.

Comment: @equaeghe Yes, it is possible but brings with it some drawbacks: The first is that one - in defining the command as you did above - gives away control about pre-notes, that can be fixed by `\newcommand*{\citenosh}{\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}\cite}`, but more importantly, try the `\citenoso{kant:kpv,kant:ku}` from above and compare with `\citenosh{kant:kpv,kant:ku}`.

Comment: Hmm, I get the error `! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite:postnote' undefined.`.

Comment: @equaeghe Oh, my bad, my MWE uses `authoryear-icomp` while you use `authoryear-comp` where the redefinitions must be slightly changed.

Comment: @equaeghe I have now added the appropriate definition for the `authoryear-comp` style.

Comment: @equaeghe Did the update help? BTW if this answer helped you and answered your question to your satisfaction, you might consider accepting and/or up-voting it.