# Unexpected output of \textcite with shorthand

Tags: biblatex

I want to use `shorthand` to abbreviate the author of a publication. Unfortunately, `\textcite` doesn't produce the expected output.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfile.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myfile.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{goossens93} \\
\parencite{goossens93} \\    
\textcite{goossens93}

\end{document}
```

Gives the following output, as expected:

```
Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin 1993
(Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin 1993)
Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin (1993)
```

When I add `shorthand = "GMS"` to the BIB entry, the output becomes

```
GMS
(GMS)
Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin (GMS)
```

but I'd expect `\textcite` to output something similar as `\cite`.

Is there a way to fix this?

I neiter want to redefine `\textcite` *globally* because there are other references without shorthands which I don't want to break nor do I want to use `\cite` instead of `\textcite` to keep the opporunity to drop the shorthand later on.

**EDIT**: 
In response to LaRiFaRi's comment: I *do* want to change `\textcite`, but only for bib-items that *have* a shorthand.

MWE2:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfile.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
%    shorthand = "GMS"
}

@book{else2015,
    author    = "Someone Else",
    title     = "Interesting thing.",
    year      = "2015"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myfile.bib}

\begin{document}

Some guys called \textcite{goossens93} wrote something about LaTeX and \textcite{else2015} also wrote something interesting. 

\end{document}
```

#1 Output: `Some guys called Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin (1993) wrote something about LaTeX and Else (2015) also wrote something interesting.`

#2 Output with shorthand: `Some guys called Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin (GMS) wrote something about LaTeX and Else (2015) also wrote something interesting.`

#3 Desired output with shorthand: `Some guys called GMS wrote something about LaTeX and Else (2015) also wrote something interesting.`

Why not globally redefine `\textcite` for all citations? As I don't want to change how `else2015` is cited.

Why not use `\cite`? As I may change my mind and drop the `shorthand` field from the BIB file. Then I want the output as in #1 - which I will only get if I don't use `\cite` instead of `\textcite`.

Comment: If you do not want to change `\textcite` *or* use `\cite` for those cases, what are you expecting to have then? Please give a complete MWE showing one citation with and one without that shorthand. Than explain, how you are citing both, what the result looks like and what you want to have. You should also mention, why you do not want to use `\cite`. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, my question was not precise in that respect. I edited it and hope that it is clearer now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\clearname{labelname}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next project, still using shorthands. As [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249211/37118) perfectly answers the question, I'll leave it marked as accepted. However, in practice that solution creates a new problem: Clearing the field `labelname` for each citekey that has a `shorthand` makes it completely impossible to use the normal citation instead of the shorthand where desired.

Therefore, this is an extended answer that draws on Ulrike's approach to

- fix the way `\textcite` is displayed when there is a shorthand field (I want to see `GMS` instead of `Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin (GMS)`)
- preserve the opportunity to avoid the shorthand.

---

Key to the solution is to use `\AtNextCitekey` to clear the `labelname` at each citation instead of doing this globally as in Ulrike's answer.

- To produce a correct shorthand citation, we need `\AtNextCitekey{\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\clearname{labelname}}}`.
- To produce a correct "long" citation, we need to clear the `shorthand` field as suggested in the second half of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229945/37118): `\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}`

To produce shorthand citations by default, I redefined `\textcite`, drawing on functionality from the `xparse` package as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29975/37118) to deal with multiple optional arguments:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldtextcite\textcite

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\textcite}{ O{} o m }{%
    \AtNextCitekey{\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\clearname{labelname}}}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1]{#3}}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1][#2]{#3}}}
```

For not having to clutter my document with `\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}` commands, I additionally defined `\textciteLong`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\textciteLong}{ O{} o m}{%
    \AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1]{#3}}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1][#2]{#3}}}
```

I hope this makes using shorthands with `authoryear` more practical. Below a full example.

---

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfile.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    shorthand = "GMS"
}

@book{else2015,
    author    = "Someone Else",
    title     = "Interesting thing.",
    year      = "2015"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myfile.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldtextcite\textcite

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\textcite}{ O{} o m }{%
    \AtNextCitekey{\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\clearname{labelname}}}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1]{#3}}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1][#2]{#3}}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\textciteLong}{ O{} o m}{%
    \AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1]{#3}}%
        {\oldtextcite[#1][#2]{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Entry without shorthand: \textcite{else2015}
    \item Entry with shorthand: \textcite{goossens93}
    \item Ignore the shorthand: \textciteLong{goossens93}
\end{itemize} 

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
• Entry without shorthand: Else (2015)
• Entry with shorthand: GMS
• Ignore the shorthand: Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin (1993)
```