# \citeyear and \citeauthor do not create hyperlinks

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing

When I use `\parencite` for example, it creates a hyperlink in the PDF which I can click to get to the reference in the bibliography. However, with `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` it does not create one. It does create a mention in the bibliography however, so that is not the problem.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I don't know all the relevant commands for this, I use a standard template found on Overleaf. But the command for my bibliography is the following:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=15,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

And the following I found in the `.cls` file:

```
\ifbool{hyperrefsupport}{% If the nohyperref class option has not been specified
\AfterPackage{biblatex}{ % Load the hyperref package after the biblatex package for compatibility 
\RequirePackage{hyperref} % Required for customising links and the PDF
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,
hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks=true, % Set to false to disable coloring links
citecolor=Crimson, % The color of citations
linkcolor=red, % The color of references to document elements (sections, figures, etc)
urlcolor=magenta, % The color of hyperlinks (URLs)
pdfstartview={FitV},
unicode,
breaklinks=true,
}\
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found how to do it for the `\citeauthor` command by adding the following to the preamble: However, I was unable to modify it to work for `\citeyear`.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}%
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: You are using `style=authoryear`, so just use `\cite*{<bibkey>}`.

Comment: See also [Getting hyperref to work with \citeyear and \citeyearpar in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83872/35864)

Comment: Reference for `\citeauthor`: [hyperlinking author names in biblatex when using \citeauthor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75902/35864), see also [biblatex+hyperref: citetitle/citeauthor and get hyperlink](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108344/35864)

Comment: Any news here? Did http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83872/35864 help you? From what I can see it is an exact duplicate of what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, that question helped me indeed! Thanks for the tips, it was indeed quite easy to solve :)